# How to prevent scrolling after hiding keyboard in ios7 html5 webapp

Tags: ios, html, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a problem with html5 app in ios7. It's easier to explain it at the screenshots:

- At the start everything is fine - https://www.dropbox.com/s/x03b2blcqjptvpi/1.jpeg?dl=0
- When I touch text input it's still ok (page scrolls down to the input)
- After blur (when keyboard is hiding) the screen is scrolling back, but over 20px too much and it looks like this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpbbd1903tfb4qt/3.jpeg?dl=0

I've tried everything (including all possibilities of apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style meta tag) and it's still not working. I wonder why ios7 scrolls my app under status bar, even if at the start of the app it's ok. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: So you have set any iOS 6/7 deltas in storyboard or xib?

Comment: As I wrote it's html5 web app - written in html & javascript and added to homescreen by Safari.